# Mongoose - how to update a child object with information from the parent automatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is a specific reason to have the information in the following way so I can't change how the parent and child object relate:

I have a parent object that contains information about a multi-day fair. There is a child object that references information for each day of the fair, each of these days is referred to as an event. I need to have the event child objects automatically generated at the time the fair object is generated. Then I need to separately generate an array of ObjectID's from the generated child objects. In addition I need to be able to generate arbitrary event objects at a later time that are not based on the fair object. That's why I have the ObjectID's array so I know what was automatically generated and what was user generated.

This is my schema (just the useful parts):

```
/**
* This is the main object, the user only supplies information for this object
* name, start and end are all provided by the user, num_days is automatically calculated
*/

var FairSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Fair name',
    trim: true
},
start_date: {
    type: Date,
    required: 'Please provide a start date'
},
end_date: {
    type: Date,
    required: 'Please provide an end date'
},
num_days: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: 1
},
events: EventsSchema
});

/**
* This is the child object it should pull all of it's information from the parent at the time the parent is created if
* the parent object has more than one day an event child object is created for each day.
*
* name: The same as the parent object, unless multiday then it's the name plus 'Day #'
* start_date: The same as the parent object unless multiday then it's the parent object time + the child object day
* end_date: the same as the parent object unless multiday then it's the parent object time + the child object day
*
*/

var EventSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please provide a name for the event',
    trim: true
},
start_date: Date,
end_date: Date,
});
```

I've tried something like this in my controller and then called it before the fair object is saved:

```
initializeFairEvents = function (fair) {
var fairLengthDays = fair.num_days;
var eventStart = Date.parse(fair.start_date);
var eventEnd = Date.parse(fair.end_date);
var one_day = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var events = fair.events;
var dailyEventLength = eventEnd - eventStart - one_day*(fairLengthDays-1);

if (events !== null && events.length > 0){}
else {
    for (var i = 0; i < fairLengthDays; i++) {
        var name, start_date, end_date, preserve;
        start_date = (i * one_day) + eventStart;
        end_date = (i * one_day) + eventStart + dailyEventLength;
        preserve = true;
        if (fairLengthDays === 1) {
            name = fair.name;
        } else {
            name = fair.name + ' - day ' + (i + 1).toString();
        }
        fair.events.push({
            name: name,
            start_date: start_date,
            end_date: end_date,
            preserve: preserve
        });
    }
}
```

};

But then I don't have ObjectID's because nothing has gone to the database to have the ID's generated.

I feel like I'm caught in a loop. Any tips or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Mongoose you can create a local model instance from the model constructors (assuming `Event` for Event) like so:

```
var event = Event();
```

Or if you only have the parent model instance (assuming `fair` for Fair) you can use the subdoc [`create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) method:

```
var event = fair.events.create();
```

You can also include an object to the constructors provided they are of the same form as the intended model. The returned instances will include object IDs automatically that will be used by MongoDB.

That said, the subdoc array `push` method should do this automatically and each array item should have an ID. None of this is of course on the remote database until you save the parent document.

```
var one_day = 86400000; // (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) no sense in computing a static value

initializeFairEvents = function(fair) {
  // Assuming fair is a model instance
  var fairLengthDays = fair.num_days;
  var eventStart = Date.parse(fair.start_date);
  var eventEnd = Date.parse(fair.end_date);
  var events = fair.events;
  var dailyEventLength = eventEnd - eventStart - one_day * (fairLengthDays - 1);

  // It looks like you only want to add events if there are no events currently
  if (events === null || events.length === 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fairLengthDays; i++) {
      var newEvent = fair.events.create({
        name: (fairLengthDays === 1) ?
          fair.name :
          (fair.name + ' - day ' + (i + 1)), 
        start_date: (i * one_day) + eventStart,
        end_date: (i * one_day) + eventStart + dailyEventLength,
        preserve: true
      });

      // newEvent.id 

      fair.events.push(newEvent);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much the create() method is, I think, exactly what I'm looking for.